# List all reports that use my report as sub report in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a `SSRS 2012` report server. I am trying to list all reports that use MyReport as a subreport. Following query gives me result.

```
USE ReportServer
GO

SELECT Path, CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)) 
FROM Catalog 
WHERE Type=2
AND CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content) LIKE '%MyReport%'
```

Is there a better standard way for SSRS 2012 like the one mentioned in [Subreport Usage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2009/03/03/subreport-usage/) for SSRS 2008?

Note: The SSRS 2008 approach didn’t work for me in SSRS 2012

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the SSRS2008 approach and it worked for me. It is the exact same code except I reference a different report server database.

Comment: This should be a comment